# how to order entities by their distance from 0 on the x axis

Tags: c#, xna, algorithm, monogame, sorting

I'm creating an infinite runner game in which you control several characters at once.  Right now when you press the spacebar, they all jump at once but, I want them to jump at separately, one after the other from right to left(largest x to smallest x) so I need to order them in some way to represent that.

I tried using bubble sort to do this with no success so I tried my own approach where I scan the screen for the x position of the characters and assign their order to the number of passes the loop has gone through:

```
public void SetJumpOrder()
    {
        int pass = 0;

        foreach (Alien a in handler.aliens)
        {
            for (int i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (i == a.position.X) a.jumpOrder = pass;
            }
            pass++;
        }
    }
```

The code above didn't work because it just gave the order of the aliens list instead.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use the built-in [Array.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort__1___0___System_Comparison___0__) or [List.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) to sort your entities, or a copy of the collection if you want to avoid mutating the original order?

Comment: If you want them to jump one after another you need to wait using some timer till Nth character jumps, then you make N+1 jump, then you make N + 2 jump. etc. Your sorting function seems fine.

Comment: @Nick I know how to make them jump at different times once their orders are the correct values. My problem is that the jump order just turns into the order of when each object was added to the list.

Comment: "The code above didn't work because it just gave the order of the aliens list instead. Any suggestions?" - well, is there a separate list of characters? If there is, loop through that. Also, when asking a question, provide the all the relevant information - we can't help you much without knowing more. How do you store the playable characters? What's the name of that variable, etc? Edit the question to include this info.